# liquid-xml not supporting exception for string attributes

Tags: liquid-xml

If a string attribute(with t_uniqueIdentifier32) is passed empty value, exception is not thrown from check restrictions. Instead leads to assertion. Using liquid-xml 2017.

Comment: How is t_uniqueIdentifier32 defined in your schema?
Which language are you generating code for?

Comment: Getting code for C++.

<xs:simpleType name="t_uniqueIdentifier32">
  <xs:annotation>
   <xs:documentation>Conforms to G2S conventions for unique identifiers - 32 characters.</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9]{3}_[ -~]{1,28}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may have been resolved in the latest 2018 version as I get an Exception as expected:

Error - Invalid Value for test [].

When I try to call

```
elm->SetTest(_T(""));
```

Where Test is defined in XSD as:

```
<xs:attribute name="test" type="t_uniqueIdentifier32" use="required" />
```

Comment: I tried using LiquidXml 2018, but the issue is still seen. Using FromXml to convert xml message to liquid object.

FromXml(LPCSTR lpszXMLIn, const CXmlSerializationContext& context = CXmlSerializationContext::GetDefaultContext());

The mentioned function returns exception for above scenario with liquid-xml (LtXmlLib5) but doesn't for 2017 and 2018.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see that. When I use elm->FromXml(_T("<root test=\"\">string</root>")); I get the Exception...Error - Failed to set the property value [].
Path: /root/@test
Invalid Value for test [].

Comment: Please create a support ticket and send a zip showing this issue: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/create-support-ticket